# Simple modern Gradle configuration to mimic default Maven Failsafe configuration

Tags: java, maven, gradle, integration-testing

What is a simple (but modern best-practices) way to configure Gradle so that it allows me to run integration tests similar to how a default [Maven Failsafe configuration](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) would work? I've read the [Gradle docs for tests](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html)—in particular the [Gradle docs for integration tests](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests)—but they seem pretty complicated (in comparison with Maven Failsafe), and moreover I don't believe the examples work in the same way.

What I'm looking for is pretty straightforward:

- There would be some separate task—let's call it `integrationTest` for the sake of discussion.
- The `integrationTest` task would *not* run when I invoke `gradle test`.
- The `integrationTest` task *would* run (after the `test` task) when I invoke `gradle integrationTest`.
- The `integrationTest` task *would* run (after the `test` task) when I invoke `gradle check`.
- The `integrationTest` task would have identical dependencies and classpath configurations as the `test` task.
- The `integrationTest` task would use the same source path (i.e. `src/test/java`) as the `test` task, but would only run tests ending in `*IT` (just to simplify the [default Failsafe inclusion pattern](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) for this discussion).
- The `test` task would ignore all tests ending in `*IT`.

That's actually a pretty simple use case. (I just went into details so there would be no ambiguity.) I can [turn that on in Failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) using two lines to indicate goals, and three lines to indicate a dependency. Since Gradle takes the XML verbosity out of the equation, I should be able to configure that in two lines, right?

Just to be clear, I don't want to use Maven Failsafe in Gradle. I just want to configure Gradle to behave in a similar way as the default Failsafe configuration, as I detailed above.

Answer (score 3):

> in particular the Gradle docs for integration tests—**but they seem pretty complicated (in comparison with Maven Failsafe)**

You're comparing a plugin (Maven Failsafe) to standard/vanilla Gradle configuration. A plugin abstracts away all the underlying details so it's not fair to compare the two. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/tree/master/maven-failsafe-plugin) of Maven Failsafe, you'll see it is equally 'complicated' compared to Gradle.

> (...) and moreover I don't believe the examples work in the same way.

The docs for configuring integration test work for typical applications. However since you have specific needs, so you'll need to adapt them.

> Since Gradle takes the XML verbosity out of the equation, I should be able to configure that in two lines, right?

No because again, you're comparing a plugin to standard/vanilla Gradle configuration. XML vs Groovy/Kotlin DSL is up for debate which is better or worse and is a matter of opinion.

For your requirements, I believe I've captured them below (untested):

```
sourceSets {
    create("integrationTest") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.test.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.get().output
    }
}

val integrationTestImplementation by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
}

configurations["integrationTestRuntimeOnly"].extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())

val integrationTest by tasks.registering(Test::class) {
    description = "Runs integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["integrationTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["integrationTest"].runtimeClasspath
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching("IT*")
        includeTestsMatching("*IT")
        includeTestsMatching("*ITCase")
    }
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}

tasks {
    test {
        filter {
            excludeTestsMatching("IT*")
            excludeTestsMatching("*IT")
            excludeTestsMatching("*ITCase")
        }
    }
    register("integrationTest", Test::class) {
        description = "Runs integration tests."
        group = "verification"
        testClassesDirs = sourceSets["integrationTest"].output.classesDirs
        classpath = sourceSets["integrationTest"].runtimeClasspath
        filter {
            includeTestsMatching("IT*")
            includeTestsMatching("*IT")
            includeTestsMatching("*ITCase")
        }
        shouldRunAfter(test)
    }
}
```

Although this is a bit verbose/awkward since you want integration tests to be within the same source set as test. So the above can be simplified to just:

```
tasks {
    test {
        filter {
            excludeTestsMatching("IT*")
            excludeTestsMatching("*IT")
            excludeTestsMatching("*ITCase")
        }
    }
    register("integrationTest", Test::class) {
        description = "Runs integration tests."
        group = "verification"
        testClassesDirs = sourceSets.test.get().output.classesDirs
        classpath = sourceSets.test.get().runtimeClasspath
        filter {
            includeTestsMatching("IT*")
            includeTestsMatching("*IT")
            includeTestsMatching("*ITCase")
        }
        shouldRunAfter(test)
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really promising, thanks! If it works I'll assign a bounty to express my appreciation. 1. Could you talk more about the how `register("integrationTest", Test::class)` is different from `task integrationTest(type: Test)`, which the official docs recommend? 2. Will using `shouldRunAfter(test)` guarantee that a failing test will fail the build before the end of the `check` task, or might Gradle schedule the integration tests _after_ `check`? (The docs recommend adding `check.dependsOn integrationTest`). 3. Is `verification` an official, documented group that other tasks use?

Comment: (1) I used the Kotlin DSL as opposed to the Groovy DSL, so syntax is different. Generally you should favor task configuration avoidance APIs (lazy APIs). (2) No, if you want to fail the build immediately for any test failure, then set the `failFast` property to `true`. Don't take the docs as the only solution, use it as a reference and tailor it to your needs. See the javadocs for `DefaultTask` for details on `dependsOn` vs `shouldRunAfter`. (3) Group is an arbitrary string value although generally plugin authors reuse existing groups. The `LifecycleBasePlugin` defines the verif. group.

Comment: In my case I have no choice but to use the Groovy DSL. I'm still not completely clear on how `register("integrationTest", Test::class)` works and if it is equivalent to `task integrationTest(type: Test)`. Any chance you could clarify that, and maybe even show part of the Groovy DSL?

Comment: Ah, it looks like Gradle has an [article](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) over this "configuration avoidance" thing you mentioned. I'll go read that and see if it answers my questions.

Comment: How this translates to Groovy is going to take a while for me to figure out. The point of the question was how to configure this in a simple way, but it looks like I'll still need to research where to set up `failFast`, where to call `register()` in Groovy, etc. So it's still not simple. I'll keep researching, but I wish I could see the complete answer in Groovy.

Comment: For the second way, is there any way to skip one kind of the tests? e.g. -DskipUnitTests and -DskipIntegrationTests?